# What are some best practices for detecting mobile devices in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mobile, 51degrees

I am enabling one of my sites to redirect certain pages to mobile versions.  Ive read blog posts by [Steve Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3/) and [Shiju Varghese](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/02/25/mobile-enabled-web-apps-with-asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery-mobile.aspx) regarding Attribute usage and 51degrees.mobi.

What I would like to have happen is a given page, dealer-locator, redirect to /mobile/dealer-locator if the device is a mobile device.  To accomplish this, I have set up an Area with the dealerlocator controller and the necessary views.  Ive tested the code directly and it seems to work properly.

When I visit the site from an actual device or FF with the user agent changed to iPhone 3.0, I get redirected to /mobile.  Is there a simple way to map page routes to mobile routes?

I should mention that the site uses isapi_rewrite and the page in question has rules that map /dealer-locator to /dealerlocator and dealerlocator is a controller.

Ive also noticed that form posts don't appear to work properly so it does a get for now.

Comment: You may want have a look on the MVC 4 beta which support mobiles. See more [here:](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features)

Answer (score 0):

From Shiju Varghese's blog post (which your question mentions), the method of the `RedirectMobileDevicesToMobileAreaAttribute` class:

```
// Override this method if you want to customize the controller/action/parameters to which
// mobile users would be redirected. This lets you redirect users to the mobile equivalent
// of whatever resource they originally requested.
protected virtual RouteValueDictionary GetRedirectionRouteValues(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    return new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Mobile", controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
}
```

can be overridden to take care of this.

In his example, everything appears to be sent to `~/Mobile/Home/Index`, but you can send the request anywhere.  He's creating a new route table, equivelant to the one you'd define in Global.asax.cs for your non-mobile routes. You could either replace your entire route table, or loop through your existing routes and return a dictionary that only contains the mobile equivelants.